# Is Typescript completely compatible with Loopback, Sails, Hapi, and Kraken?

Tags: typescript, sails.js, loopbackjs, hapi.js, kraken.js

Our firm is choosing a Javascript framework to write a large app with server logic and a RESTful API.

Since we're using Typescript for everything I was worried to see that some frameworks might have issues with it - i.e. [they expect Javascript formatted a very specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572943/how-to-use-typescript-with-loopback).

Can anyone who's actually worked with one of these frameworks in Typescript tell me if there are any problems we'll run into using any of the four major frameworks: Loopback, Sails, Hapi, Kraken?

Comment: The cited answer doesn't contain anything unfamiliar to TS adept. There shouldn't be problems with *any* framework, as long as you're proficient with TS.

Comment: I agree with @estus, and furthermore getting generic advice on issues between frameworks is too broad for so. :)

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894297/using-typescript-with-sails/45496702#45496702) I show how to create a model, view, controller with typescript and provide an example project that I started but never finished. There also seems to be some hapi typescript projects out there that a google search will point you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone who's actually worked with one of these frameworks in Typescript tell me if there are any problems we'll run into using any of the four major frameworks

Any issues you face will be with JavaScript. Valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript. Most issues in a conversion process can be silenced with using `any` type.